# Bypass stuck audio jack on macbookpro with software

Tags: macbook-pro, audio, headphones, firmware

Can i create a mac Osx application that can bypass the audio jack to produce sound through the speakers. I accidentally broke off the headphone jack inside my Macbook Pro and sound no longer comes out, this is clearly a software issue since the internal speakers produce sound on startup but subsequently become "disabled" once logged in.

Can't I spoof the MacBook Pro using software to think that the headphone jack is disconnected even if it is.

Comment: In System Preferences, under "sound" you should be able to override the default output and output to speakers

Comment: Unfortunately the headphone detection is a hardware switch, and there's no way I've found or heard of to override it (short of tinkering with your computer's internals). Your best bet is to figure out how to remove the broken-off plug from the jack.

Comment: Thanks @timothymh you may be right but the strange thing is on startup the speakers play the apple "ding" sound and in bootcamp on windows you can bypass the speakers

Comment: @NoahL usually works but the problem is that the headphone jack triggered the optical audio out which makes it impossible to choose internal speakers in sound preferences.

Comment: @Tuesday  It isn't a hardware problem if you reboot and the boot "chime" is heard over the speakers.

Comment: @mankoff Yep, I was wrong. This has been addressed more usefully in the questions this one has been marked as a duplicate of.